# Filter for next value

Tags: qgis, query, filter

I'm working with QGIS 3.28.5.
I'm working on breeding bird data. I have a set of points where I heard a bird on a specific date. Now I want to separate the territories.
My problem is, that I have to go to the query builder every time I finished working on the territories of one species.

Is there a way in QGIS to set the filter "just show all attributes with one species value and then the next one and the next one"
As an example: I filter for "species" = 'Blackbird' and when finished I go back to the builder and filter for "species" = 'Robin'.

Does somebody have a suggestion or a recommendation for a plugin?

Comment: You could categorise your data and turn off all categories you're not interested in at the moment?

Comment: Thank you. Didn't think of this easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something close to this using Python Actions.

Action 1 - Set Filter:

Create a Python Action to Set the filter such that only features matching an attribute of the current feature are shown. You can modify the following code to suit your needs:

```
from qgis.utils import *
layer = iface.activeLayer()
actionfilter = "species= '[%species%]'"
layer.setSubsetString(actionfilter)
```

This will set a filter on the layer to show all features with the same 'species' value.

Action 2 - Remove Filter:

Create a Python Action to remove any filters on the layer such that all features are shown:

```
from qgis.utils import *
layer = iface.activeLayer()
actionfilter = ""
layer.setSubsetString(actionfilter)
```

You can learn more about Actions [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html?highlight=actions)